# Remove Column in R after an "if" clause

Tags: r

I am learning R and I have a R data table in which I want to remove unnecessary features (unnecessary table columns). For this I am using the ReliefexpRank algorithm from the CORElearn package, with table and originaltable being the R tables.

```
library(CORElearn)

estRelifF <-attrEval(FLAG_READMITIDO_MEAN ~.,table,estimator="ReliefFexpRank",ReliefIterations=30)

for( i in estRelifF ){
if(estReliefF[i]==0) {originaltable[i]<-NULL}
}

output <-data.frame (estReliefF)
```

I know that the estReliefF has the correct results, getting me results like this sample below for each feature

```
LOCAL
-4.428817e-01
HORA
0.000000e+00
```

And I want to remove the Hora one which is 0.

I don't know what the problem is though I suspect that's around the IF statement, since it's my first time using R I would appreciate some help since I can't seem to find the mistake.

Comment: Please, provide a short reproducible example of your data so we can run your code and find the error.

Comment: Well as I said the data in estReliefF is a vector with data in the format I mentioned and originaltable is just a regular database-like table in which I want to remove the columns in which estReliefF vector has 0. Like for example the Hora one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from you modifying your columns while running a loop on them. Let's say your vector and table are :

```
x<-c(1,1,0,1,0)
df<-data.frame(1:5,2:6,3:7,4:8,5:9)
```

If you run `for(i in 1:5){if(x[i]==0){df[i]<-NULL}}`, you'll see that the third column has been removed, but not the fifth. That's because after the third column has been removed, the fifth column is no longer the fifth but the fourth, and `x[4]`is not null.

You need to find all the unwanted columns before deleting them : one possible solution is :

```
df[-which(x==0)]
```

Comment: Hmm I assumed that in this particular vector i would be the key (LOCAL,HORA,etc....) therefore therefore that problem would not occur.

Comment: Well you don't use LOCAL, HORA and so on, you use `estReliefF[i]`. That just means "the i-th column", regardless of its name.